# Extract the word from String using Regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following

**Input:**

```
 abc_account2621_activity_20161116_20161117_030627_311999667.csv
 xyx_account2622_click_2016111606_20161116_221031_311735299.csv
 sed_account2623_impression_2016111605_20161116_221808_311685411.csv
 abc_account2621_rich_media_2016111606_20161116_192542_311735300.csv
 vbc_account2622_match_table_activity_cats_20161116_20161117_0311_31.csv.gz  
 sbc_account2622_match_table_activity_types_20161116_20161117_0342_31.csv.gz
```

**Expected Output**

```
activity
click
impression
rich_media
match_table_activity_cats
match_table_activity_types
```

**Code Tried up till now:**

I want to access word which lies between [Number + (-)Underscore and End with  (-)Underscore + Number]

```
 val x = "abc_account2621_match_table_activity_types_20161116_20161117_0342_31.csv.gz"

 val pattern3 = "(_([A-Za-z]+_[0-9]))".r
 var word=pattern3.findFirstIn(x).getOrElse("no match")
 word: String = _types_2
```

Comment: does this one `sbc_account2622` always end in number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val x = "abc_account2621_match_table_activity_types_20161116_20161117_0342_31.csv.gz"
val pattern3 = """_([a-zA-Z_]+)_\d+""".r
pattern3.findAllIn(x).matchData.map(_.group(1)).toList
```

`_([a-zA-Z_]+)_\d+` with `matchData` to capture `group` can capture this.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Q9r1Wx/1) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to find non number:

```
abc_account2621_([\D]+)_
```

For xyx_abc_... use:

```
([^_]+_[^_]+_)([\D]+)_
```

Comment: abc_account2621_ this word is not constant it can change it can be xyz_acb2145 etc

Answer (score 1):

I often find pattern matching with regex patterns to be handy.

```
val pattern = """\d_(\D+)_\d""".r.unanchored
input.collect{case pattern(x) => x}
// res0: List(activity, click, impression, rich_media, match_table_activity_cats, match_table_activity_types)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one : 
`\d_([a-zA-Z_]+)_[0-9]+_`
with the flag set to global.
try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/3Jbjer/2)